# django-bootstrap3 how to get required and error classes working in template

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my registration form I have:

```
    class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
        required_css_class = 'required'
        error_css_class='error'


        username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
                                    max_length=30,
                                    label=_("Username"),
                                    error_messages={'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters.")})
        email = forms.EmailField(label=_("E-mail"))
        password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                    label=_("Password"))
        password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                    label=_("Password (again)"))

        first_name=forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
                                    max_length=30,
                                    label=_("first name"),
                                    error_messages={'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters.")})
        last_name=forms.RegexField(regex=r'^[\w.@+-]+$',
                                    max_length=30,
                                    label=_("last name"),
                                    error_messages={'invalid': _("This value may contain only letters, numbers and @/./+/-/_ characters.")})

.................
```

In my template that uses django-bootstrap3:

```
{% extends "registration/base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap3 %}
{% bootstrap_css %}
{% bootstrap_javascript %}

{# Display django.contrib.messages as Bootstrap alerts }
{% bootstrap_messages %}


{% block title %}Registration{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <h1>Sign up</h1>
      <p>Already registered?
        <a href="{% url 'django.contrib.auth.views.login' %}">Sign in here.</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <form action="{% url 'registration_register' %}"
        method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="form-group has-error">
    {% bootstrap_form form layout='horizontal' %}

    {% buttons %}
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
        {% bootstrap_icon "star" %} Sign Me Up!
      </button>
    </div>
   </div>
    {% endbuttons %}
  </form>

</div>
{% endblock %}
```

I am attaching a snapshot of the `registration form`:
Three things I want to fix: 
1. There is not `*` for the `required field`. It is missing although I have `required_css_class = 'required'` in the `form`

2. All the `fields` are initially boxed in red (indication of error). the box should light up in red only when there is some error in `form fields`.
3. possible way to override the `label` of `form fields` in `template` from what is assigned in the form using `label attribute`

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You have wrapped your form in a `form-group has-error` class form and then your field are always rendered as field with error. You can safely remove this div tag because bootstrap_form tag automatically add a `form-group` class div around  your fields.

```
<form action="{% url 'registration_register' %}"
        method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% bootstrap_form form layout='horizontal' %}
    {% buttons %}
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                {% bootstrap_icon "star" %} Sign Me Up!
            </button>
        </div>
    {% endbuttons %}
</form>
```

You can produce custom labels for your fields if you avoid bootstrap_form tag and using individual renderer for each field

```
<form action="" method="post" role="form" class="form-horizontal">{% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <div class="form-group{% if field.field.required %} required{% endif %}">
            <div class="col-md-2 control-label">
                {% bootstrap_label 'your custom label' %}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                {% bootstrap_field field show_label=False form_group_class=None %}
            </div>
        </div>
   {% endfor %}
   {% buttons %}
      <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                {% bootstrap_icon "star" %} Sign Me Up!
            </button>
       </div>
   {% endbuttons %}
</form>
```

Finally, maybe you can't see a * beside required field because you don't set appropriately your css:

```
.form-group.required .control-label:after {
    content:"*";
    color:red;
}
```

I have also removed from your `RegistrationForm` class the line

```
error_css_class = 'error'
```

and I have set as optional the two last fields of your forms just for test the code presented.

In the following an image that show the results of the presented code

[image]